# Would microelectrodes reach a steady state current if convection is negligible and only pure diffusion occurs?

Tags: electrochemistry, diffusion

Assuming a two dimensional Cottrell type problem with a micro-electrode and a high enough applied potential so that concentration of the consumed redox species would be zero near the surface. Naturally the concentration profile would have a semi-spherical symmetry and boundary layer.
In the case of linear diffusion, the boundary layer grows infinitely if we consider a semi-infinite domain.
Is this still the case for semi-spherical diffusion with a micro-electrode in the middle of the cell? or does it reach a steady state?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It does reach a steady state.

---

We consider the electrochemical *academic* reaction
$$\ce{O + ne^- <=> R} \tag{R1} $$
to keep things simple, let $C$ be the concentration of species $\ce{O}$.

The concentration of species $\ce{O}$ is found by solving Fick's second law in cylindrical coordinates
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D\nabla^2 C =
  \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial C}{\partial r} + 
  \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial z^2} = 0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient of species $\ce{O}$, and $\partial C/\partial t = 0$ because we are interested in the steady-state solution. The semi-infinite problem has the following boundary conditions:

- Far away in the radial direction from the UME the concentration is equal to the bulk concentration (denoted with $C^*$), which gives a Dirichlet boundary condition
  $$ \lim_{r \to \infty} C(r, z) = C^* \tag{2}$$
- Far away in the axial direction from the UME the concentration is equal to the bulk concentration, which gives a Dirichlet boundary condition
  $$ \lim_{z \to \infty} C(r, z) = C^* \tag{3}$$
- Zero flux of matter in the axial direction, because no reaction takes place outside the UME, which gives a Neumann boundary condition
  $$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial z}(r, 0) = 0 \quad \forall r>r_0  \tag{4} $$
  where $r_0$ is the radius of the UME.
- There is a uniform concentration over the face of the electrode (denoted by $C_0$), which gives a Dirichlet boundary condition
  $$ C(r, 0) = C_0 \quad r \leq r_0 \tag{5}$$

Newman solved this problem by a suitable variable transformation. We will define a concentration change and two new variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ which satisfy
\begin{align}
  \Delta C &= C^* - C(r, z) \tag{6} \\
  r &= r_0[(1 + \xi^2)(1 - \eta^2)]^{1/2} \tag{7} \\
  z &= r_0 \xi \eta \tag{8}
\end{align}
Don't worry about the geometrical meaning of these coordinates, because at the end we will come back at the cylindrical coordinates. The partial differential equation along with the boundary conditions take the following form
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\left[(1 + \xi^2)
  \frac{\partial \Delta C(\xi,\eta)}{\partial \xi}\right] +
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}\left[(1 - \eta^2)
  \frac{\partial \Delta C(\xi,\eta)}{\partial \eta}\right] &= 0 \tag{9} \\
  \lim_{\xi \to \infty} \Delta C(\xi, \eta) &= 0 \tag{10} \\
  \frac{\partial \Delta C}{\partial \eta}(\xi,0) &= 0 \tag{11} \\
  \Delta C(0, \eta) &= C^* - C_0 \tag{12} \\
\end{align}

The good news is that this PDE problem has a solution by separation of variables. Omitting the details we arrive at the concentration profile
\begin{equation}
  \Delta C(\xi,\eta) = \left[1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(\xi)
  \right](C^* - C_0) \tag{13}
\end{equation}

Now we need to find the steady-state current density. This can be evaluated by Faraday's law
\begin{align}
  j &=  nFD\frac{\partial C(r,z)}{\partial z}\bigg\vert_{(r,0)} \\
  j &= -nFD\frac{\partial \Delta C(r,z)}{\partial z}\bigg\vert_{(r,0)} \\
  j &= -nFD\left[\frac{\partial \Delta C(\xi,\eta)}{\partial \xi}
  \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z}\right]_{(0,\eta)} \tag{14} \\
\end{align}
Eq. (14) needs the calculation of two partial derivatives. The first one comes from Eq. (13) while the third one from Eq. (8), and both are pretty direct
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial \Delta C}{\partial \xi} &= -
  \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)\frac{C^* - C_0}{1 + \xi^2} \tag{15} \\
  \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z} &= \frac{1}{r_0\eta} \tag{16}
\end{align}
additionally, we put $\eta$ as a function of $r$ and $\xi$. This is again direct with Eq. (7) by just isolating $\eta$
\begin{align}
  \eta &= \sqrt{\frac{1 + \xi^2 - (r/r_0)^2}{1 + \xi^2}} \tag{invert} \\
  \frac{1}{\eta} &= \sqrt{\frac{1 + \xi^2}{1 + \xi^2 - (r/r_0)^2}}
  \tag{multiply by 1/$r_0$} \\
  \frac{1}{r_0\eta} &= \frac{1}{r_0}\sqrt{\frac{1 + \xi^2}{1 + \xi^2 - (r/r_0)^2}}
  \\
  \frac{1}{r_0\eta} &= \sqrt{\frac{1 + \xi^2}{r_0^2[1 + \xi^2 - (r/r_0)^2]}} \\
  \frac{1}{r_0\eta} &= \sqrt{\frac{1 + \xi^2}{r_0^2(1 + \xi^2) - r^2}} \\
  \frac{1}{r_0\eta} &= \sqrt{\frac{1 + \xi^2}{r_0^2 + r_0^2\xi^2 - r^2}}
  \tag{17} \\
\end{align}
Combining Eqs. (14)-(17)
\begin{align}
  j &= -nFD\left[-\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)\frac{C^* - C_0}{1 + \xi^2}
  \sqrt{\frac{1 + \xi^2}{r_0^2 + r_0^2\xi^2 - r^2}}\right]_{(0,\eta)}  \\
  j &= -nFD\left[-\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)(C^* - C_0)
  \sqrt{\frac{1}{r_0^2 - r^2}}\right] \rightarrow
  j = \frac{2nFD(C^* - C_0)}{\pi\sqrt{r_0^2 - r^2}} \tag{18}
\end{align}
We need one last step, because we are searching for the current. Since the current density depends on the radial coordinate, and the element of surface is $2\pi r\mathrm{d}r$, integrating yields
\begin{align}
  i &= \int j \, \mathrm{d}S \\
  &= \int_0^{r_0} \left(\frac{2nFD(C^* - C_0)}{\pi\sqrt{r_0^2 - r^2}}\right)
  \, (2\pi r\mathrm{d}r) \\
  &= 4nFD(C^* - C_0) \int_0^{r_0} \frac{r\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{r_0^2 - r^2}} \\
  &= 4nFD(C^* - C_0) [-\sqrt{r_0^2 - r^2}]_0^{r_0} \\
  &= 4nFD(C^* - C_0) (-0 + \sqrt{r_0^2}) \rightarrow
  \boxed{i = 4nFDr_0C^*} \tag{19}
\end{align}
Eq. (19) is the value of the steady-state current under thec conditions you are serarching. The applied potential is so high, that the concentration $C_0 \approx 0$. Thus, by only knowing the concentration of $\ce{O}$ far away from the electrode, its diffusion coefficient, and the radius of the UME you can calculate its steady-state current.

---

**References**

A discussion about this problem can be found in Chapter 5 of the following book:

- A. J. Bard, L. Faulkner, and H. S. White, Electrochemical Methods: Fundamentals and Applications, John Wiley & Sons, New York, 2022.

Newman's paper is free to download here:

- https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/1.2424003